# Calculate all possible sum combinations in a given array of space delimited numbers using BASH

Tags: bash, combinations

Is there a way to calculate all possible sum combinations in a given array of space delimited 'n' numbers using pure BASH?

**example:** 2 3 4....n

**Output:** 5 7 6 9 and so on

Comment: Why are 2, 3, and 4 excluded?

Comment: The output requires sum of the digits in the given list or array, not the elements themselves

Answer (score 2):

Use an indicator to tell what elements to sum. You can implement it as an array of ones and zeros, where 1 means *include in the sum*. To walk around all the combinations, just start with an array of ones of the same length as the array of the numbers, implementing binary decrement is easy. Skip the computation if the indicator has only one 1, as you don't want the numbers alone included. To report each sum just once, use an associative array to hold the sums.

```
#!/bin/bash
sum () {
    sum=0
    for n in "$@" ; do
        ((sum += n ))
    done
    printf %d "$sum"
}

numbers=(2 3 4)
indicator=()
for _i in "${numbers[@]}" ; do
    indicator+=(1)
done

declare -A sums

while si=$(sum "${indicator[@]}") ; (( si > 0 )) ; do
    if (( si != 1 )) ; then
        sum=0
        for ((i=0; i<${#numbers[@]}; ++i)) ; do
            (( indicator[i] && (sum+=numbers[i]) ))
        done
        sums[$sum]=1
    fi

    # Binary decrement.
    i=0
    until (( indicator[i] || i > ${#indicator[@]} )) ; do
        indicator[i++]=1
    done
    indicator[i]=0
done
echo "${!sums[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can do it but it requires Python3 :

```
import itertools
numbers = [2, 3, 4]
print(list(itertools.chain(*list(map(lambda x: x, 
     [list(map(sum, list(itertools.combinations(numbers,x)))) for x in range(2, len(numbers) +1)]
     )))))
```

Will print :

```
[5, 6, 7, 9]
```

I don't think Bash is the right tool for this if you want it to be dynamic and fast.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable answer, but I particularly require it to be in BASH itself. Any ideas? Thanks